# Does the MKR WIFI 1010 support the arduino mouse and keyboard controller?

Tags: bluetooth, arduino-due, arduino-leonardo, arduino-micro, mkr1010

I am working on a project right now that needs to connect to my computer via bluetooth and access the arduino mouse and keyboard library. In my research, I've found that only the Leonardo, Due, and Micro can emulate cursor movements, but they need to have additional hardware like the HC05. I would like to keep the amount of hardware I use to a minimum, but I understand if there is no way around it. Is there any way to use the MKR WIFI 1010 like a Leonardo, or would I need to get one of the aforementioned boards and then get a bluetooth module hooked up?

PS this is my first dive into bluetooth, so any additional resources to aid me in my journey would be much appreciated.

Comment: the USB magic is in the microcontroller ... compare the boards by microcontroller

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the Arduino SAMD boards are supported by the Arduino Keyboard and Mouse library.

Nano 33 IoT is a smaler alternative to MKR 1010.

But the MKR1010 or the Nano33 IoT with original NINA firmware doesn't yet support classic Bluetooth like the HC-05 module. The ArduinoBLE library and the NINA firmware support only BLE which is different.

But there is a simple way to replace the NINA firmware with the ESP32 Arduino basic Bluetooth sketch SerialToSerialBT and then use it from the SAMD. This way the NINA module will be degraded to something like a HC-05.